# How to use safearea at the Appbar?

Tags: flutter

So I was trying to make an appbar that has an image and text, but the image got cropped because I use the safe area widget. Anyone know the solution? i have tried to use

> bottom:false

at the safe area widget

[image]

here is the code:

```
 title: SafeArea(
          bottom: false,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: deviceData.height * 0.05,
                width: deviceData.width * 0.10,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage(
                          "https://cdn.popbela.com/content-images/post/20190314/cover-526b71db133e78000df9ead475e858f1_750x500.png",
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              Container(
                height: deviceData.height * 0.05,
                width: deviceData.width * 0.3,
                child: Text("Nadine Amizah",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
```

Comment: this may causing               height: deviceData.height * 0.10,

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by using toolbarheight at the appbar